# Process luminance value (Y') of video pixels using AVFoundation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macos, avfoundation

I'm having trouble accessing the luminance value in the pixels of a video. The video I'm using is all black so I'd expect the luminance value to be close to 0. That's true for pixels in the top half of the video, but not so much for the bottom half--which is why I think I'm reading things the wrong way.

Video settings set above:

```
[videoSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8Planar] forKey:(NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];
```

Here's my code:

```
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer); 

    // Lock the image buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0); 

    // Get information of the image
    uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer); 

    NSLog(@"dimensions: %lu x %lu", width, height);

    for (uint y = 0; y < height; y += pixelSkipHeight)
    {
        uint8_t *p = baseAddress + y * bytesPerRow; // this gets Y' in YUV

        for (uint x = 0; x < width; x += pixelSkipWidth)
        {

           if (x == 33 * 20)
                NSLog(@"color at %dx%d: %u", x, y, p[0]);

        }


    }

    // Unlock the image buffer
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);


    CMSampleBufferInvalidate(sampleBuffer);
    CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
    sampleBuffer = nil; // NULL?
```

Here's my output:

```
2012-02-08 10:29:12.142 MyApp[5193:15103] dimensions: 1920 x 1080
2012-02-08 10:29:12.143 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x0: 0
2012-02-08 10:29:12.144 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x33: 5
2012-02-08 10:29:12.145 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x66: 3
2012-02-08 10:29:12.146 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x99: 4
2012-02-08 10:29:12.146 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x132: 4
2012-02-08 10:29:12.147 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x165: 4
2012-02-08 10:29:12.148 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x198: 4
2012-02-08 10:29:12.149 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x231: 5
2012-02-08 10:29:12.150 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x264: 5
2012-02-08 10:29:12.151 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x297: 3
2012-02-08 10:29:12.152 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x330: 5
2012-02-08 10:29:12.154 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x363: 4
2012-02-08 10:29:12.156 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x396: 6
2012-02-08 10:29:12.157 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x429: 6
2012-02-08 10:29:12.158 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x462: 7
2012-02-08 10:29:12.159 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x495: 5
2012-02-08 10:29:12.160 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x528: 3
2012-02-08 10:29:12.161 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x561: 6
2012-02-08 10:29:12.162 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x594: 2
2012-02-08 10:29:12.163 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x627: 4
2012-02-08 10:29:12.164 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x660: 4
2012-02-08 10:29:12.165 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x693: 6
2012-02-08 10:29:12.166 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x726: 128
2012-02-08 10:29:12.168 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x759: 129
2012-02-08 10:29:12.169 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x792: 128
2012-02-08 10:29:12.171 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x825: 129
2012-02-08 10:29:12.172 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x858: 128
2012-02-08 10:29:12.175 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x891: 128
2012-02-08 10:29:12.177 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x924: 128
2012-02-08 10:29:12.177 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x957: 128
2012-02-08 10:29:12.198 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x990: 128
2012-02-08 10:29:12.199 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x1023: 128
2012-02-08 10:29:12.200 MyApp[5193:15103] color at 660x1056: 127
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the specifics of this pixel format but if it is planar then isn't the image going to be something like:

```
Plane 1 [Y0 Y1 ... YN]
Plane 2 [U0 U1 ... UN/4]
Plane 3 [V0 V1 ... VN/4]
```

In your output the first two thirds are luminance samples and the last third is the two chrominance parts at quarter resolution each, as I'd expect. You seem to be expecting interleaved samples.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y.27UV420p_.28and_Y.27V12_or_YV12.29 I think the coloured table there explains what I mean quite well.

Comment: Also note that the chrominance samples are around 128 which is the same as no colour as chroma is usually offset to the centre value.

Comment: I'm by no means an expert either. Here's what MediaInfo gives me if this helps: Color space                      : YUV, 
Chroma subsampling               : 4:2:0, 
Bit depth                        : 8 bits

Comment: You already said it was `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8Planar`.

Comment: I think I got it! I replaced uint8_t *p = baseAddress + y * bytesPerRow; with uint8_t *p = baseAddress + y * width; and I now get numbers that I'd expect. Thanks for your help koan!